What are examples of application of Pauli gates to three-qubit states?
The matrix math from Quantum Computation and Quantum Information is always at most for two qubits, which left the subject vague and unclear to me. So I have a three qubit entangled superposition that I want to do operations on.
$$
a|000\rangle + b|011\rangle + c|101\rangle + d|110\rangle
$$
I want to use any pauli gate operation on any of the qubits, first second or third. My question is, can I get an example of how such operations would be carried out?

Sure.
Say you want to apply an $X$ gate to the middle qubit, then you need to compose the operator $U$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
U &=  I \otimes X \otimes I
\\
\\ 
U &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
U &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
U &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
Since your statevector in column-vector form is given by:
$$ |\psi_0 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ 0 \\0 \\ b \\ 0 \\ c \\ d \\0 \end{bmatrix}$$
you can then perform matrix multiplication:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\psi_1 \rangle &= U |\psi_0\rangle
\\
\\
|\psi_1 \rangle &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ 0 \\0 \\ b \\ 0 \\ c \\ d \\0 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
|\psi_1 \rangle &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ b \\ a \\ 0 \\ d \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ c \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
Which in ket form is given by:
$$ |\psi_1 \rangle = b|001\rangle + a|010\rangle + d|100\rangle + c|111\rangle $$
And this is exactly what you would expect from applying an $X$ gate to the middle qubit.

Can you tell me if this is present anywhere in a textbook like quantum computation and quantum iinformation? Because I looked and couldn't find it.

Sorry, I don't know. It is very likely they do specify how to generalize for a larger number of qubits, but maybe they just leave it as an exercise to deal with particular examples.
